# Powershell Convertto-json output

Tags: json, powershell

Im getting a stream from shopify with powershell and converting it json readable text.
It was working fine for a couple of weeks but now is not returning the same data format.

```
$uri = "https://yourshop.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/orders.json?limit=250"
$apikey = ""
$password = ""
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($apikey+":"+$password))}
$products = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -FollowRelLink -contentType "application/json" -Method Get -Header $headers -Body $Body -MaximumFollowRelLink 5 
$products | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 | Out-File C:\json\ordersdepth5.json -encoding utf8
```

it used to return neat json

```
{
    "orders":  [
                   {
                       "id":  4059713634402,
                       "admin_graphql_api_id":  "gid://shopify/Order/4059713634402",
                       "app_id":  580111,
                       "browser_ip":  "120.154.83.138",
                       "buyer_accepts_marketing":  true,
                       "cancel_reason":  null,
                       "cancelled_at":  null,
```

but now it returns
`["{\"orders\":[{\"id\":4122462257250,\"admin_graphql_api_id\":\"gid:\\/\\/shopify\\/Order\\/4122462257250\",\"`
A bunch of slashes and rubbish

Is there an issue with the data stream? what should I look at.

Shopify wouldn't change formatting unless there is an api change?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by moving the data into powershell to convert from and then convert to json.

```
$products | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 -Compress |Out-File C:\json\ordersdepth2.json -encoding utf8
```